# Android feedly client with full article cache for offline reading

Tags: android, offline, dark-theme

I need a [feedly](http://www.feedly.com/) client for Android with the following characteristics:

Required:

- Ability to cache full article for offline read.
- Ability to select the refresh and download period based on network condition (only when connected in a Wi-Fi network).
- Ability to select external SD card as the default place to store the cached articles.
- Ability to select the default font size to read the article.
- Ability to choose between a dark and a light theme.

Wanted:

- The most simple and clean design as possible.

It could be a free or a paid app. If it's paid, it should be nice if it have a trial version.

In fact, I am looking for something most similar as possible from [Flux](http://www.windowsphone.com/pt-br/store/app/flux/3c8daa82-bad5-df11-a844-00237de2db9e) for Windows Phone, because it works very well and have a simple and clean design.