# Android app for reading news subscriptions offline?

Tags: android, offline

I have paid subscriptions to several news site, like the Wall Street Journal, New York Times, etc. I'm looking for an Android app that:

1. Allows me to enter my login information for these subscriptions
2. Schedule downloads of the news articles for when I'm connected to a network
3. Read the downloaded articles and see associated comments, images, etc. *offline*.

Does such an app exist? Apps like [Feedly](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17107/android-feedly-client-with-full-article-cache-for-offline-reading) don't allow me to save articles for offline reading, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

There was [GReader Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.noinnion.android.greader.readerpro) which I still use and it's great, but unfortunately it's not developed anymore; an alternative might be [Palabre](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.levelup.palabre).
Both apps can sync with your Feedly account and download the data offline but cannot display comments (such as Disqus) when the network is not present.